# how to handle repeated entries coming in the pivot table & power query to populate in excel dashboard

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery, dashboard

I have got two tables **capacity** and **demand**

**Capacity table looks like this:**

| RESOURCE NAME | SKILL GROUP | PROJECT | START DATE | END DATE | COST PER HOUR | CAPACITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resource 1 | Automation Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Mar-2022 | 12.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 2 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Mar-2022 | 11.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 3 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 12.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 4 | Report Testing | Project 2 | 1-Oct-2021 | 30-Apr-2022 | 12.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 5 | CICD and Devops | Project 3 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Mar-2022 | 11.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 6 | Performance Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Mar-2022 | 12.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 7 | Automation Testing | Project 2 | 1-Nov-2021 | 31-Mar-2022 | 10.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 8 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Mar-2022 | 12.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 9 | Report Testing | Project 1 | 1-Dec-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 11.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 10 | Cloud Testing | Project 1 | 1-Dec-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 11.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 11 | Report Testing | Project 3 | 1-Dec-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 12.0 | 800.0 |
| Resource 12 | Pipeline Testing | Project 1 | 1-Dec-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 11.0 | 900.0 |
| Resource 13 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 1-Dec-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 12.0 | 800.0 |

**Demand Table looks like this:**

| RESOURCE NAME | SKILL GROUP | PROJECT | START DATE | END DATE | DEMAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resource 1 | Automation Testing | Project 2 | 1-Oct-2021 | 25-Oct-2021 | 200.0 |
| Resource 2 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 300.0 |
| Resource 3 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 400.0 |
| Resource 1 | Report Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 200.0 |
| Resource 4 | CICD and Devops | Project 3 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Mar-2022 | 300.0 |
| Resource 5 | Performance Testing | Project 2 | 1-Oct-2021 | 25-Oct-2021 | 400.0 |
| Resource 6 | Automation Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 200.0 |
| Resource 2 | Cloud Testing | Project 2 | 1-Oct-2021 | 25-Oct-2021 | 300.0 |
| Resource 7 | Report Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 400.0 |
| Resource 8 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 800.0 |
| Resource 9 | Report Testing | Project 2 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 800.0 |
| Resource 10 | Pipeline Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 600.0 |
| Resource 11 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 700.0 |
| Resource 10 | Performance Testing | Project 2 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 250.0 |
| Resource 11 | Automation Testing | Project 1 | 1-Oct-2021 | 31-Dec-2021 | 250.0 |

I merged these two tables using power query on the basis of **resource name** and trying to generate the below pivot table.

**Pivot table screenshot**
[image: Pivot table screenshot]

My common field in both the table is **"Resource Name"**, what I am trying to build in pivot table which will be further used in my dashboard with slicer. Trying to build dashboard like this.

**Dashboard screenshot**
[image: Dashboard Screenshot]

**Challenging points:**

- Not able to capture the Capacity Hours and Total capacity Cost, Cost is getting repeated. Other values from **Hours** & **Cost** sections are fine Demand hours & Total Demand as per the pivot table above.

**PowerQuery Merge Screenshot**

[image: Power Query Screenshot]

**FinalTable Screenshot**

[image: FinalTable Screenshot]

After that I choose "Close & Load" with option selected to "Upload to data model"

**Here is the final Table look like:**

| RESOURCE NAME | SKILL GROUP | PROJECT | START DATE | END DATE | COST PER HOUR | CAPACITY | DemandTable.RESOURCE NAME | DemandTable.SKILL GROUP | DemandTable.PROJECT | DemandTable.DETAIL | DemandTable.START DATE | DemandTable.END DATE | DemandTable.DEMAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resource 1 | Automation Testing | Project 1 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 12 | 800 | Resource 1 | Automation Testing | Project 2 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 25-10-21 0:00 | 200 |
| Resource 1 | Automation Testing | Project 1 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 12 | 800 | Resource 1 | Report Testing | Project 1 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 200 |
| Resource 2 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 11 | 900 | Resource 2 | DB Testing | Project 1 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 300 |
| Resource 2 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 11 | 900 | Resource 2 | Cloud Testing | Project 2 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 25-10-21 0:00 | 300 |
| Resource 3 | DB Testing | Project 1 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 12 | 800 | Resource 3 | DB Testing | Project 1 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 400 |
| Resource 4 | Report Testing | Project 2 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 30-04-22 0:00 | 12 | 200 | Resource 4 | CICD and Devops | Project 3 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 300 |
| Resource 5 | CICD and Devops | Project 3 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 11 | 800 | Resource 5 | Performance Testing | Project 2 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 25-10-21 0:00 | 400 |
| Resource 6 | Performance Testing | Project 1 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 12 | 900 | Resource 6 | Automation Testing | Project 1 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 200 |
| Resource 7 | Automation Testing | Project 2 | 01-11-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 10 | 250 | Resource 7 | Report Testing | Project 1 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 400 |
| Resource 8 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-03-22 0:00 | 12 | 900 | Resource 8 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 800 |
| Resource 9 | Report Testing | Project 1 | 01-12-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 11 | 800 | Resource 9 | Report Testing | Project 2 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 800 |
| Resource 10 | Cloud Testing | Project 1 | 01-12-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 11 | 900 | Resource 10 | Pipeline Testing | Project 1 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 600 |
| Resource 10 | Cloud Testing | Project 1 | 01-12-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 11 | 900 | Resource 10 | Performance Testing | Project 2 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 250 |
| Resource 11 | Report Testing | Project 3 | 01-12-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 12 | 800 | Resource 11 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 700 |
| Resource 11 | Report Testing | Project 3 | 01-12-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 12 | 800 | Resource 11 | Automation Testing | Project 1 |  | 01-10-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 250 |
| Resource 12 | Pipeline Testing | Project 1 | 01-12-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 11 | 900 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Resource 13 | Cloud Testing | Project 3 | 01-12-21 0:00 | 31-12-21 0:00 | 12 | 800 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**Queries:** 
**CapacityTable**

`let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CapacityTable"]}[Content], #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"RESOURCE NAME", type text}, {"SKILL GROUP", type text}, {"PROJECT", type text}, {"START DATE", type datetime}, {"END DATE", type datetime}, {"SUN", type any}, {"MON", type number}, {"TUE", type number}, {"WED", type number}, {"THU", type number}, {"FRI", type number}, {"SAT", type any}, {"COST PER HOUR", Int64.Type}, {"CAPACITY", Int64.Type}}) in #"Changed Type"`

**DemandTable**

`let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DemandTable"]}[Content], #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"RESOURCE NAME", type text}, {"SKILL GROUP", type text}, {"PROJECT", type text}, {"DETAIL", type any}, {"START DATE", type datetime}, {"END DATE", type datetime}, {"SUN", type any}, {"MON", type number}, {"TUE", type number}, {"WED", type number}, {"THU", type number}, {"FRI", type number}, {"SAT", type any}, {"DEMAND", Int64.Type}}) in    #"Changed Type"`

**FinalTable**

`let Source = Table.NestedJoin(DemandTable, {"RESOURCE NAME"}, CapacityTable, {"RESOURCE NAME"}, "CapacityTable", JoinKind.LeftOuter), #"Expanded CapacityTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "CapacityTable", {"RESOURCE NAME", "SKILL GROUP", "PROJECT", "COST PER HOUR", "CAPACITY"}, {"CapacityTable.RESOURCE NAME", "CapacityTable.SKILL GROUP", "CapacityTable.PROJECT", "CapacityTable.COST PER HOUR", "CapacityTable.CAPACITY"}) in #"Expanded CapacityTable"`

Problem is that when I am trying to build the data through pivot table for capacity vs demand for all my projects and resources, my capacity hours are getting repeated for each records which are present in my Demand Table. I believe I need to get my data populated on the basis of Project, however, not sure what need to be done.

Comment: I suggest you add the code that you have used to try to obtain your desired results; along with a screenshot of your desired results; and information as to what you expect the slicer to do.  It might help to read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is, your description of your desired results, phrased as a Q&A, is too vague.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I have updated the questions as per your input and suggestions.

Comment: I managed to fix all the issues to create the above dashboard, however, just stuck on the capacity hours and cost which is getting repeated for to all the resource present in the Demand sheet. I tried fixing this using power queries joins and other options, however, no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to make some changes in either your flow or your code. But I don't see how I can help you with that, given what you have posted so far.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld as explained in the question, I just merged my capacity & demand table using powerquery, and in my PivotTable, as Demand table has the same resource name duplicated, but when I merged the Demand and Capacity tables I ended up duplicating the Capacity amount for each matching resource name in the Demand table. In my above example data, resources 1, 2 and 11 are listed multiple times in the Demand table and the total Capacity is listed at the amount at the resource level for each project.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I believe I need to split the capacity values down to a project level, or only report demand vs capacity at the resource level, however, not able to understand how to do this.

Comment: I cannot help you further. You seem unable or unwilling to provide sufficient information for me to be able to reproduce your problem. Consider that there are various ways to "merge tables" in Power Query. If you are duplicating entries, then you are not doing it correctly. But since I don't know how you are doing this, and you refuse to supply the code that would demonstrate what you are doing (along with your input/output for that step), all I can tell you is that you need to change your code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i update the question with some more screenshots, let me know if I missed something.

Comment: I still don't see the **CODE** you are using.   When you do something in the UI in PQ, M-Code is generated. To see the code that is generated, you open the `Advanced Editor`.  You can then copy/paste that information ***as text*** into your question.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I have updated the question with query code for all of my 3 tables. CapacityTable, DemandTable & FinalTable.

Comment: I see what you are doing. But a problem with your data and the PT you are trying to create is that, for example, in your data there is no Capacity for `Resource1/project2` but you show demand in your desired PT for that combination. How is that?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, If you see the final table generated after the merge has got all the records of Demand table, In my PT I am selecting the resources, projects, demand and total demand (i.e. cost per hours from capacity table * demand hours in demand table). My challenge is that my capacity hours respective to resources are getting repeated, hence breaking the results. Ideally, I should get my capacity broken at resource level in demand table against each resources matching with capacity table. For example, Resource 1 capacity in FinalTable shows two 800, however, it should be 400 each

Comment: Why `400` each?  Your source data shows `800` cap for `res1/proj1` and no entry for `res1/proj2`.  So shouldn't it be `800` and `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the Pivot Table you are showing, but without duplicating data, you can:

- Join the two tables based on `{"RESOURCE NAME","PROJECT"}` using `JoinKind.FullOuter`
- Expand the table and "fill in the nulls" in the `PROJECT` and `RESOURCE NAME` columns for the rows that are missing an entry from either the Capacity or Demand tables
- Add Demand*Cost column.
- After cleaning things up, you can Save And Load To a Pivot table.

**M Code**

```
let

//Lodad and Type Capacity Table
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Capacity"]}[Content],
    Capacity = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,{
        {"RESOURCE NAME", type text}, {"SKILL GROUP", type text}, {"PROJECT", type text}, 
        {"START DATE", type date}, {"END DATE", type date}, 
        {"COST PER HOUR", Currency.Type}, {"CAPACITY", Number.Type}}),

//Lodad and Type Demand Table    
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Demand"]}[Content],
    Demand = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"RESOURCE NAME", type text}, {"SKILL GROUP", type text}, {"PROJECT", type text}, 
        {"START DATE", type date}, {"END DATE", type date}, {"DEMAND", Number.Type}}),

//Join the two tables
    joined = Table.NestedJoin(Capacity,{"RESOURCE NAME","PROJECT"},Demand,{"RESOURCE NAME","PROJECT"},"Joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),

//Remove unneeded columns and expand the Joined table
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(joined,{"SKILL GROUP", "START DATE", "END DATE"}),
    #"Expanded Joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Joined", 
        {"RESOURCE NAME", "PROJECT", "DEMAND"}, 
        {"Demand.RESOURCE NAME", "Demand.PROJECT", "Demand.DEMAND"}),

//Transform the null records for those missing from one table or the other
    capFN = {"RESOURCE NAME", "PROJECT", "COST PER HOUR","CAPACITY"},
    demFN = {"Demand.RESOURCE NAME", "Demand.PROJECT", "Demand.DEMAND"},
    recs = Table.ToRecords(#"Expanded Joined"),
    xForm = List.Generate(
        ()=>[rec = recs{0}, idx=0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(recs),
        each [rec = if recs{[idx]+1}[RESOURCE NAME] = null or recs{[idx]+1}[Demand.RESOURCE NAME]= null then 
            let 
                rtl = Record.ToList(recs{[idx]+1}),
                xRtl = if rtl{0} = null then List.ReplaceRange(rtl,0,2, List.Range(rtl,4,2)) 
                    else List.ReplaceRange(rtl,4,2, List.Range(rtl,0,2)) 
            in Record.FromList(xRtl, List.Combine({capFN,demFN}))
            
                        
                        else recs{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
        each [rec]),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(xForm, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", 
        {"RESOURCE NAME", "PROJECT", "COST PER HOUR", "CAPACITY", "Demand.DEMAND"}, 
        {"RESOURCE NAME", "PROJECT", "COST PER HOUR", "CAPACITY", "Demand.DEMAND"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{
        {"RESOURCE NAME", type text}, {"PROJECT", type text}, 
        {"COST PER HOUR", Currency.Type}, 
        {"CAPACITY", Int64.Type}, {"Demand.DEMAND", Int64.Type}}),

//Add demand*cost column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Demand Cost", each [COST PER HOUR]*[Demand.DEMAND], Currency.Type),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"COST PER HOUR"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

### =>

[image]