# Showing top 5 records in Excel Dashboard using Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have got a pivot table data as below.

**Pivot Table Data:**

| Row Labels | CAPACITY | DEMAND | Capacity-Demand | SurplusResourceUtilization |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resource 1 | 1600 | 1100 | 500 | TRUE |
| Resource 10 | 1800 | 1500 | 300 | TRUE |
| Resource 11 | 1600 | 950 | 650 | TRUE |
| Resource 2 | 1800 | 1200 | 600 | TRUE |
| Resource 3 | 800 | 400 | 400 | TRUE |
| Resource 4 | 200 | 300 | -100 |  |
| Resource 5 | 800 | 900 | -100 |  |
| Resource 6 | 900 | 200 | 700 | TRUE |
| Resource 7 | 250 | 400 | -150 |  |
| Resource 8 | 900 | 800 | 100 | TRUE |
| Resource 9 | 800 | 900 | -100 |  |

I am trying to show top 5 records where my "**SurplusResourceUtilization**" column has value "True" or "**Capacity-Demand**" value greater than (>) 0 .

I tried using both below formulas.

```
=IFERROR(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Resources!A3:D15,Resources!E3:E15="TRUE")),4,-1),"")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Resources!A3:D15,SUMIF(Resources!A3:A15,Resources!A3:A15,Resources!D3:D15)>0))),"")
```

But both are giving all the records matching, in my case it is returning 7 records. Seems I am missing some matching criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A3:D15,(D3:D15>0)+(E3:E15=TRUE),""),4,-1),{1;2;3;4;5},{1,2,3,4}),"")
```

Comment: using above formula my results are getting populated horizontally, i need it vertically.

Comment: Got this fixed with few changes `=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A3:D15,(D3:D15>0)+(E3:E15=TRUE),""),4,-1),{1;2;3;4;5},{1,2,3,4}),"")`

Comment: Sorry, I swapped the delimiters @techmaster.

Comment: No worries, I am working to create a dashboard in excel and I am stuck with on issue, I have posted it in separate question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243997/how-to-handle-repeated-entries-coming-in-the-pivot-table-power-query-to-popula.